# Python: Making a list that includes functions but has as-yet undefined arguments

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

Generally, what I would like to do is make a list that involves some function or functions, but the argument of that function will change based on an "i" of a for loop, and so the argument is not fully defined when I define the list. 
Imagine func(x) and I wanted a list like [func(x * i), func(x * i**2)], for instance. Meaning, there will be some argument x that is defined, but I want to modify it by "i", the iterator in a for loop.
Specifically, what I am trying to do is build a 2D array out of a certain pattern (represented by a list) that will center around the diagonal of the array. However, the values of the pattern change depending on the row of the array I am at. So I keep track of which row we're at, and use that "i" value as an argument in the function.
The problem is that when I define the list, it tries to evaluate the function, and crashes because i is not as yet defined (it will be defined once we go through the for loop)
Is there some way to delay the evaluation of the functions in the list until it enters the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that for your 2d array there are better ways of defining the diagonal than iterating through the rows and calculating a function like this.  But to focus on the issue of 'delaying' the evaluation of a function I'll try this:

Define a simple function

```
In [438]: def func(x):
   .....:     return x**2
   .....:
```

This list definition does not work because the interpreter is trying to evaluate `x*i` before passing them to `func`.  It is going to use what ever `x` and `i` it has at hand.

```
In [442]: [func(x*i),func(x*i**2)]
...

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Instead I can wrap each function call inside another function call. It could be a named function or as I do here an unnamed `lambda`.  Just like the body of `func` the `x*i` is delayed until the lambda is called:

```
In [443]: [lambda x,i:func(x*i), lambda x,i: func(x*i**2)]
Out[443]: [<function __main__.<lambda>>, <function __main__.<lambda>>]

In [444]: flist=_   # assign that list to a new name for later use
```

Now we can define an `x` and `i` and evaluate the functions in the list:

```
In [445]: x=np.arange(3)    
In [446]: i=2
In [447]: [f(x,i) for f in flist]
Out[447]: [array([ 0,  4, 16]), array([ 0, 16, 64])]
```

or we can wrap that in iteration over `i`:

```
In [449]: [[f(x,i) for f in flist] for i in range(3)]
Out[449]: 
[[array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0])],
 [array([0, 1, 4]), array([0, 1, 4])],
 [array([ 0,  4, 16]), array([ 0, 16, 64])]]
```

Which I could even turn into a 3d array with:

```
In [450]: np.array(_)
Out[450]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  1,  4],
        [ 0,  1,  4]],

       [[ 0,  4, 16],
        [ 0, 16, 64]]])
```

An alternative is to parameterize the wrapping function

```
In [451]: def func1(x,i,p=1):
   .....:     return func(x*i**p)

In [452]: [[func1(x,i,p) for p in [1,2]] for i in range(3)]
Out[452]: 
[[array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0])],
 [array([0, 1, 4]), array([0, 1, 4])],
 [array([ 0,  4, 16]), array([ 0, 16, 64])]]
```

`functools` has a `partial` function that lets me specify some of the arguments of a function while delaying full evaluation:

> partial(func, *args, **keywords) - new function with partial application of the given arguments and keywords.

```
In [461]: from functools import partial

In [462]: flist=[partial(func1,p=1), partial(func1,p=2)]

In [463]: [[f(x,i) for f in flist] for i in range(3)]
Out[463]: 
[[array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0])],
 [array([0, 1, 4]), array([0, 1, 4])],
 [array([ 0,  4, 16]), array([ 0, 16, 64])]]
```

In fact if I tweak `func1` I can assign both `i` and `p` with partial:

```
In [464]: def func1(x,i=0,p=1):
    return func(x*i**p)

In [465]: flist=[partial(func1,p=1), partial(func1,p=2)]    
In [466]: fflist=[[partial(f,i=i) for f in flist] for i in range(3)]

In [467]: fflist
Out[467]: 
[[functools.partial(<function func1 at 0xb4d3e3d4>, i=0, p=1),
  functools.partial(<function func1 at 0xb4d3e3d4>, i=0, p=2)],
 [functools.partial(<function func1 at 0xb4d3e3d4>, i=1, p=1),
  functools.partial(<function func1 at 0xb4d3e3d4>, i=1, p=2)],
 [functools.partial(<function func1 at 0xb4d3e3d4>, i=2, p=1),
  functools.partial(<function func1 at 0xb4d3e3d4>, i=2, p=2)]]
```

Evaluating this still requires iteration through the nested list:

```
In [471]: [[f(x) for f in ff] for ff in fflist]
Out[471]: 
[[array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0])],
 [array([0, 1, 4]), array([0, 1, 4])],
 [array([ 0,  4, 16]), array([ 0, 16, 64])]]
```

I could have created `fflist` with one call to `partial` (for each 'cell'):

```
fflist=[[partial(func1,i=i,p=p) for p in [1,2]] for i in range(3)]
```

It might be possible to streamline the iteration by making `fflist` an object dtype array, but that's a latter question.

There are other ways of wrapping functions for later evaluation, but these are the simplest and most obvious.

I could use `partial` with the `x` argument as well

```
In [478]: z=[[partial(f,x) for f in ff] for ff in fflist]

In [479]: z
Out[479]: 
[[functools.partial(<function func1 at 0xb4d3e3d4>, array([0, 1, 2]), i=0, p=1),
  functools.partial(<function func1 at 0xb4d3e3d4>, array([0, 1, 2]), i=0, p=2)],
 ....]]

In [480]: [[f() for f in ff] for ff in z]
```

Comment: I appreciate that you actually answered the question of delaying evaluation instead of worrying about what I am trying to do with it and how I can avoid using such a method for my task. Too often on SE people try to rewrite your code, and not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Define the list inside the loop:

```
for i in whatever:
    l = [func(x * i), func(x * i**2)]
```

Given that you've tagged this NumPy, using a list at all may not be a good idea, but we can't really tell what you should be doing from the question as asked.

Comment: I just thought of that, but the problem is that the lists (3 to be exact) are all arguments of the function. The program crashes when it tries to initialize the argument.

Comment: @MattF: Either you've designed this function wrong, or you're trying to use it wrong. You'll have to change some aspect of your design to make this work. It's really hard to tell what you're describing, so I can't say what part you'll have to change.

Comment: I am creating a diagonal matrix whose diagonal is a repeating pattern. as such, I am iterating through the list to place the appropriate item in the appropriate column. There may well be a NumPy function that creates such diagonal matrices, which is why I tagged it.
I could post the code, if that will be helpful, but if there is a Pythonic way to delay evaluation as Mathematica would do, that would be easiest